# How can kotlin coroutine can be executed sequential?

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine

I have this AudioTrack class which is getting stream of audio data in bytestring. I was using AsyncTask for this which was working fine. But as I moved to kotlin I was not able to get it working. In AsychTask data is written sequentially and Audio play is smooth. But in kotlin when I play audio it is mixed up.

I have tried to use suspend, async But I failed.

Java -

```
class PlayAsynchTask : AsyncTask<Void, Void, String?>() {
    var byteString: ByteString? = null

    override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void?): String? {
        val data = byteString?.toByteArray()
        if (audioTrack != null && data != null) {
            if (audioTrack?.state == AudioTrack.PLAYSTATE_PAUSED) {
                audioTrack?.play()
            }
            try {
                audioTrack?.write(data, 0, data.size)
            } catch (ex: Exception) {

            }
        }
        return null
    }

}
```

Kotlin

```
fun wavPlay(byteString: ByteString?) {
    val wavData: ByteArray? = byteString?.toByteArray()
    aPlayJob = GlobalScope.launch {
        audioTrack?.play()
        audioTrack?.write(wavData!!, 0, wavData.size)
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it make a difference if you move `val wavData: ByteArray? = byteString?.toByteArray()` into the Coroutine scope?

Comment: You can also use `AsyncTask` in **Kotlin** also same way you did in **Java**. Concerning about `Coroutines`, if you want your work to be on background thread then use *Coroutine Scope* & *Dispatchers* for it.

Comment: @Smashing No it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: @JeelVankhede Yeah I can use AsyncTask, but just wanted to learn coroutine, because of less boilerplate code and easy cancellation so.

Comment: Okay, in such case, you can use suggested approach with *CoroutineScope & Dispatchers*

Comment: @JeelVankhede I am not sure how CoroutineScope & Dispatchers would help here. As far as I understand CoroutineScope is for scoping of coroutine like application level, activity level. And Dispatchers is for type of thread selector like for UI thread or new thread. Can you provide some example for your suggestion.

Comment: Not exactly sure how it's writing out of order unless you are launching multiple times within your write function. As an example for dispatchers, you can typically use it to switch contexts (ie to a background thread), do some execution, then go back to the ui thread. Assuming that you want to handle something in the ui after you write, this would be a good place to do it. If instead you with to provide constant ui updates (which is what async task can do), you may want to look into channels. Channels allow you to submit data from any coroutine, then listen with one context.